# Interactive frontend for the command-line that "linkifies" text

Tags: web-apps, command-line

Does anyone know of an existing customisable frontend to command-line apps/scripts whose most basic function would work something like this

- executes commands like `ps -aefH`
- based on configurable regexes patterns like PIDs are recognised and turned into links
- when a link beneath a PID is clicked a menu appears presenting other commands to run that would receive the PID as an argument (e.g. show memory stats, dump core, send signal)

Thanks!

Comment: That would "prepare" the next command line, right? Very cool idea, I would certainly use it :-)

Comment: Ah, important: For what operating system and shell? bash on Linux?

Comment: You tagged "web-apps"... Does it mean you are currently typing commands via some kind of web interface?

Comment: Yes, I suppose there could be an option to prepare the next command-line rather than just execute it. I'm using a linux terminal, but the reason for a web-app is that I don't think terminals allow you to easily "enrich" a command's output with links (and potentially also documentation bubbles, etc..). With a browser extension like Tridactyl it could still be keyboard-based. If there's no existing projects & I start developing one unsure of what platform to use, but it should be able to run programs written in any language. OS portability shouldn't be too hard either.

Comment: Edit this into your question please. Comments can disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse allows plugins to register pattern matchers on the console, that can then be used to decorate the console with hyperlinks. If an Eclipse-based frontend is OK for you, then these are resources that can get you started:

- [Pattern matcher extension point](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_console_consolePatternMatchListeners.html)
- [addHyperlink method on TextConsole](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/console/TextConsole.html#addHyperlink(org.eclipse.ui.console.IHyperlink,%20int,%20int))

I did something similar before to decorate Stacktraces in the console output of Java programs.